# How to use semaphores to synchronize two processes so I can have the desired output in C?

Tags: c, process, synchronization, semaphore

I have two processes ( a parent and a child - I did that using fork).

[image]

I want to synchronize the two processes using semaphores, so that the output is just "a=20".

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

sem_t sem1;
sem_t sem2;
int a=0;

int main() {
    sem_init(&sem1, 0, 1);
    sem_init(&sem2, 0, 1);

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        sem_wait(&sem1);
        a = 10;
       if (a == 10) {
            printf("a = %d\n", a);
       }
       sem_post(&sem2);
    } else {
        sem_wait(&sem1);
        a = 20;
        if (a == 20) {
            printf("a = %d\n", a);
        }
       sem_post(&sem2);
        wait(NULL);
    }

    sem_destroy(&sem1);
    sem_destroy(&sem2);

    return 0;
}
```

I want the outcome of that code to be always "a=20" but when I run it I get the result "a=20 a=10".

First the child process gives 'a' the value 10. Then the parent process overwrites the value of 'a' to 20. Then we enter the 'if' statement of parent process, checks if a=20 and prints it. Then the child process checks if a=10 but 'a' does not equal to 10 because the parent process gave to 'a' the value of 20, but "a=10" still gets printed and I cannot understand why.

The problem is I want the part where the child checks if a=10 to stay there but don't get a=10 printed on the screen. I want the output to be just a=20.

Comment: But you *are* aware that by `fork`ing each process gets its own copy of `a`? If you want to get this running you need to install some shared memory or use other means of communication between the processes. Apart from it doesn't look right to me that both processes wait for the same semaphore at first – which only seems not to block for the semaphores not being correctly initialised. And the semaphores should only be destroyed by the process that created them, so you should do so within the `else` block after `wait`ing.

Comment: Not only does each process have its own copy of `a`, each also has its own copies **of the semaphores**.  It's not sufficient to initialize them as process-shared (which, in fact, the program does not do).  These too must reside in shared memory (alternatively, named semaphores could be used instead of anonymous ones).  However, @Aconcagua, even if they were shared, it would not be necessary for the same process to destroy the semaphores as created them.  They should not *both* do it, but in practice, they don't either one need to do it since the program is about to terminate anyway.

Comment: I'd recommend stepping backwards a bit: First skip the semaphores and make sure first that the two processes actually can access the same `a` via shared memory. To get there just let your processes sleep a little while one modifies the variable and the other one reads it like [here (yet without shared memory)](https://godbolt.org/z/3fb1hrM3n). If you get one process to see the change of the other one you're ready for the next step (the semaphores).

Comment: @JohnBollinger Well, indeed – but destroying them at the time I proposed (after waiting) makes sure they don't get destroyed while the other process yet might rely on...

Comment: Maybe you might want to let the processes communicate via pipes instead? This is quite a bit easier to handle and wouldn't require semaphores (or are you explicitly experimenting with these?).

Comment: I am required to use semaphores.. It's not my choice how I do it

Comment: Rather than defining lots of shared variables (including the semaphores), define a `struct` type containing the shared items (including the semaphores) as members. The size of this `struct` type is the minimum size of the shared memory segment you will need to allocate. Hints: Call `shmget` with the first parameter set to `IPC_PRIVATE` to get an anonymous shared memory segment. Call `shmat` to get a pointer to the shared memory segment. Convert that to a pointer to your `struct` type. You can initialize the shared memory contents before the fork. The child will inherit the shared memory.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming this is running on Linux. You have three problems.

The first is that you are trying to synchronise two processes. When you are sharing a semaphore between two processes, according to the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_init.3.html), you need to

- the second parameter must be non zero
- the semaphore must be located in shared memory. Ordinary global memory is not shared.

Your second problem is that both the parent and the child wait on `sem1` and then post to `sem2`. That means one of the threads will block forever probably (according to the man page, sem_destroy causes undefined behaviour if there are processes waiting when it is called), but you can't tell which one. What you need to do is make sure the child process gets to `a = 10;` first but the comparison second. You need some synchronisation between the assignment and the comparison.

Your third problem is that each process has its own copy of `a`. This, like the semaphores needs to go into shared memory.

---

To expand on the synchronisation point, you need something like this (using pseudocode):

```
Parent
------

initialise shared memory
initialise sem1 and sem2 and a all to 0
fork

wait on sem1
set a = 20
if a == 20 print
post on sem2

Child
-----
set a = 10
post on sem1
wait on sem2
if a == 10 print
```

sem1 is used to signal that the child has set a to 10. sem2 is used to signal that the parent has set a to 20 and printed.

Depending on your architecture and hardware, you may have to make `a` `volatile` to disable optimisations that keep it in registers and have a memory barrier to make sure it gets flushed from CPU cache to main memory.